# Why SortedSet was removed from stdlib in Ruby 3.0?

Tags: ruby, ruby-std

That was a very surprising finding when I switched my app to Ruby3+ version.

Even though it is a major version upgrade but still..

Removal of *Core data type* from stdlib that's been there for at least 10 years(since 1.9.3?) looks weird.

Was there any compelling reason I'm not aware of?

The error that it raises:

> "The `SortedSet` class has been extracted from the `set` library. You must use the `sorted_set` gem or other alternatives."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bit of searching I found the following:

[Remove SortedSet implementations PR](https://github.com/ruby/set/pull/2)

> It required RBTree to perform decently and the external dependency was not suitable for a standard library. The pure ruby fallback implementation was originally meant to be a demonstration of how to write a subclass of Set, and its poor performance was not suitable for use in production.
>
> I decided it should be distributed as an external library instead of bundling it with Set.

---

To keep it short:

> SortedSet has been removed for dependency and performance reasons.

[source](https://github.com/ruby/set/blob/v1.0.0/CHANGELOG.md)